# Ensure sidebar sticky goes to the bottom of the viewport when scrolled down

Tags: html, css, position, sticky

https://jsfiddle.net/fw8ozvqh/

When the page is not scrolled, the sidebar meets the bottom of the page properly and content in the sidebar can still be scrolled all the way to the bottom.

[image]

However, once the page scrolls, the sidebar is off the bottom of the page by the size of the navbar + margin. This is expected, however, is there a way to ensure the sidebar sticks to the bottom of the viewport as well after scrolling the body?

[image]

Solutions that involve absolute or fixed positioning are not sufficient for me, as I'd like to keep the sidebar in the flow of the document.

```
html, body {
  height: 1200px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.sidebar {
  background: green;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px - 32px);
  position: sticky;
  top: 32px;
  margin-top: 32px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<header>
   header
</header>

<div class="sidebar">
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
  <div>sidebar content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using interaction observer to detect when sticky is triggered and then removed the header height from the calc. Not a perfect solution, but gets the job done in my use case. A better solution would be nice.